# How to redirect search.php?query=test&search=1&s=1 to /query/test

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have tried other things, but I cannnot get it to work, when I go to the main website, (index.php is just a include of search.php) it will send me to this `/query/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/query/?query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=query&search=1&s=1`
The .htaccess rule I have is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^query/([A-Za-z0-9]+) /search.php?query=$1&search=1&s=1  [QSA]
```

I want `search.php?query=test&search=1&s=1`  to goto `/query/test/`
UPDATE:
After I updated the .htaccess to say

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^query/([A-Za-z0-9]+) search.php?query=$1&search=1&s=1  [QSA]
```

It would load but still the
`/query/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/search.php/query/?query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=search&search=1&s=1&query=query&search=1&s=1`
Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I found out my issues, the reason why it was redirecting like that was because of cache, I tested it on a new browser and it worked. I just had to tweak some of my code, if interested I can leave a link to it below. But my new .htaccess is

```
#.htaccess for https://sturtz.cf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^query/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/(1|3) search.php?query=$1&search=1&s=$2  [QSA]
RewriteRule ^query/ search.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^search.php?query=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&search=1&s=(1|3) /query/$1/$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^query/?query=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&search=1&s=1 /query/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^query/?query=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&s=1&activesearch=0 /query/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^query/search.php?query=([A-Za-z0-9]+)&search=1&s=1 /query/$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: So, what did you "tweak" exactly? The directive you posted in your question is actually doing the _opposite_ of what you are asking?

Comment: Yeah, this is really not useful for anyone who finds your question later.

Comment: Sorry, let me edit my answer, 
EDIT: @MrWhite fixed